# Web content filter (including HTTPS)

Tags: networking, website-blocker

Small business looking for a content filter that prevents employees from going to non work related websites. We have been using Kerio WinRoute Firewall until now, but we it does not support filtering HTTPS.

Requirements:

1. Able to categorize websites
2. Whitelist/blacklist
3. Can filter HTTPS requests (we have a clear company policy stating any web traffic on work computers is subject to filtering and logging)

We will buy a new server if necessary. Can be Windows/Linux based as long as it is easy to administer.

Comment: BlueCoat ProxyClient is good. You might also want to use McAfee Web Gateway which is really good too but it is cloud based and it is a proxy web filtering solution. (or just use the on premise solution)

Comment: Does it matter if it's a product meant to run on each client machine, rather than on a single server box?

Comment: @TechnikEmpire We would prefer something on a single server box.